# Retrieve Kerberos token via SSPI by username

Tags: winapi, kerberos, sspi

Is there way to retrieve user token locally without password?

Comment: Do you want to access the TGT with session key or just the Kerberos UPN of the user?

Comment: now for me works well a such chain: AcquireCredentialsHandle(KERBEROS,SECPKG_CRED_BOTH); InitializeSecurityContextA(SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP); with username and password. But i have some magic library which can retrieve acceptable by server token without password. i need the same functionality